# Monogame resizing GraphicsDeviceControl in WindowsForms?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm currently working on a custom Map editor using Windows Forms.

I have a class inheriting from GraphicsDeviceControl (called MapDisplay) that I'm using so that I may use spritebatch to draw the map onto the form. I have this map display control inside of a split panel on my form, and it adjusts its size depending on the size of the map that's loaded. Currently I use `mapDisplay.Width` and `mapDisplay.Height` to change it's size, then use `mapDisplay.Invalidate()` so it redraws.

The problem comes when the width or height of the map display gets above a certain amount, it goes blue and stops working. How do I stop this from happening?

Cheers!

Comment: How big does it get before it displays blue?

Comment: It looks like 4096 x 4096 is the max width x height.

Comment: I believe you are reaching the max texture size. Instead of creating a really large texture and then trying to display that, render a partial view of your map.